Text within text box to mirror selected filter title - Looker Studio
I'm trying to get text within a text box to mirror the selection title within a drop down menu. For example, if I have a drop down menu which lists all of my Google search Console profiles, I need the text in the text box to mirror the selected profile title.
Drop Down
fr.example.com
**uk.example.com**
de.example.com

Text in box: **uk.example.com**

Is there a way of achieving this?
I cannot find a example of how to do this
